# Powershell - View Website Source Information

Tags: internet-explorer, powershell

There are some websites, such as gmail.com that don't display source information (i.e. you cannot right-click and select "View Source")

So I am trying to read the document source into a file so I can see the different types of elements (I would like to be able to pass credentials and other data into websites eventually), but I'm having difficulty.

Here is the code:

```
$ie = new-object -com "InternetExplorer.Application"
$ie.navigate("http://www.gmail.com")
$ie.visible=$true
$doc = $ie.document
Add-Content C:\output.txt $doc.all
```

C:\output.txt is blank, help!

Comment: Have you considered simply running Fiddler or a similar tool?

Comment: You mean Fiddler, http://fiddler2.com/ ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem with using `InternetExplorer.Application` is you then have to handle the application behaviour, for example if I run your code I also get an empty file, because the page loaded after the document property was accessed.

If you are using Powershell v3, you can use the `Invoke-WebRequest` cmdlet to directly query the webserver as follows:

```
$webreq = Invoke-WebRequest http://www.gmail.com
$webreq.Content |Out-File C:\temp\output.txt
```

In powershell v2 you can use the `System.Net.Webrequest` .NET class as follows:

```
$req = [System.Net.WebRequest]::Create("http://www.gmail.com/")
$resp = $req.GetResponse()
$reqstream = $resp.GetResponseStream()
$stream = new-object System.IO.StreamReader $reqstream
$result = $stream.ReadToEnd()
$result | out-file c:\temp\output2.txt
```

Comment: This solution works. When I output $result to the console I can read clearly, but when I output to .txt file, everything is jumbled. What filetype can I pipe $result to?

Comment: What do you mean by "jumbled"? if output to console or to file and then read the file, both are the same... as you woudl expect since the source is the same.

Comment: @ Graham Gold: Oh, I mean that the output is not neatly organized into lines and tab delimited as it is when $result it piped to console. When I output $results into .txt file, everything is bunched up together, not separated by spaces and tab delimited

Comment: I presume you are opening in notepad? It is not the greatest at handling carriage return/ line feed. Try wordpad or notepad++

Answer (score 2):

You can view the source of any website. I am able to see the source for Gmail on Chrome, using the normal method of right click -> View page source.

You can  also open up Developer Tools -> Elements to see source.

In Chrome, you can even use a URL like `view-source:https://mail.google.com/mail/u/0/?shva=1#inbox` to view source.

Going the route of getting the source from Powershell will only get more and more complicated.