# Invoke-WebRequest for PowerShell Version 2

Tags: powershell, windows-server-2003

What is the equivalent to Invoke-WebRequest function in PowerShell Version 2. This is what I am trying to doing with my function as I cannot upgrade to PowerShell 4 because I am working on Windows Server 2003.

```
Invoke-WebRequest $uri -Body ($baseMessage | ConvertTo-Json -Compress) -Method Post -ContentType "application/json"
```

Thank you

Comment: PowerShell 3.0 is not available for Windows Server 2003.

Answer (score 3):

```
$Web = New-Object System.Net.WebClient
$Web.OpenRead($url)
$PageContents = New-Object System.IO.StreamReader($Web)
$PageContents.ReadToEnd()
```

If you're looking to submit JSON data you can use this instead:

```
$Encoding = [System.Text.Encoding]::GetEncoding("ASCII")
$postArray = $Encoding.GetBytes($json)
$Web = [System.Net.WebRequest]::Create($url)
$Web.Method = "POST"
$Web.Timeout = 10000;
$Stream = $Web.GetRequestStream()
$Stream.Write($postArray, 0, $postArray.Length)
$Web.GetResponse()
```

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.Net.WebClient_methods(v=vs.80).aspx

Found another similar question on stackoverflow:

[PowerShell WebRequest POST](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22921529/powershell-webrequest-post)

Comment: This doesn't quite work. Exception that says " Calling OpenWrite with "2" arguments"

Comment: Can you tell me exactly how my statement would look using this ? Invoke-WebRequest requires attributes such as -Body, -ContentType, and -Method

Answer (score 1):

You can use `System.Net.Webrequest` .NET class in powershell v2 instead.

See this example from one of my powershell answers:
[Powershell - View Website Source Information](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18450227/powershell-view-website-source-information/18454205#18454205)

And also answer to this shows how to set json content type, albeit in C# 
[How to get json response using system.net.webrequest in c#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2108297/how-to-get-json-response-using-system-net-webrequest-in-c)

Comment: Can you tell me exactly how my statement would look using this ?
Invoke-WebRequest requires attributes such as -Body, -ContentType, and -Method

Comment: If you check the msdn reference for System.Net.Webrequest you will see it has the properties you need : https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webrequest%28v=vs.110%29.aspx